# Context Path is not working in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing a web-app using spring boot and I have added context path in the application.properties file given below but when I am running the application it is not using the context path.

"I have added #Context Path server.port=8085
server.servlet.context-path=/nvs-councellor in application.properties file"

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/JSP/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp


# create and drop tables and sequences, loads import.sql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update


#Turn Statastics on
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=debug

# Show all queries
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
# PostgreSql settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://10.226.1.10:5444/NVS_COUNSELLOR
spring.datasource.username=cefipra
spring.datasource.password=cefipra
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=nvs_counsellor
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect


#Context Path
server.port=8085
server.servlet.context-path=/nvs-councellor
```

"When I am running the application with url http://localhost:8080/nvs-councellor/COUNSELLOR it shows the correct page but when i perform other action it is giving me 404 with following url http://localhost:8080/loginAction"

Comment: Since you have added context path you have to include that for the api's also, so URL : `http://localhost:8080/nvs-councellor/loginAction`

Comment: @Avi- Do I need to append **/nvs-councellor** with every request mapping ??

Comment: no, not in `@RequestMapping` when you call from UI or from another service you have to include that

Comment: @Avi- But in other spring boot applications in which I am working, there is no need to do that. context path needs to automatically append to incoming request

Comment: for client what are you using ?

Comment: I am using JSP for client side

Answer (score 0):

@Shubham Gadekar - Just remove / from where you are calling any action or href
For example- action="loginAction" in place of action="/loginAction"
It works for me so please try at your end. Thanks.